Does UK skilled visa holder (Tier 2 visa holder) with Indian passport need a visa to travel to Mexico?
If it’s needed, how can I get visa for Mexico ?

Your temporary resident status in the UK does not exempt you from needing a visa to enter Mexico.
You can request an appointment to apply for a visa here
See also Mexican government site

First link is broken.

@DJClayworth I can open it and there’s a ‘Visa and passports’ option bottom right.

@DJClayworth Below the large-font "Visa and passport" on the linked page in Traveller's answer appears a line with smaller type within a horizontal black band: "Emirates > Before You Fly > Visa and Passport > Visa and Passport Information Results." Click on the words "Visa and Passport" that appear within the horizontal black line.

I’m not sure I understand why you say OP is not visa-exempt, when any UK multiple-entry visa gives an exemption?
